# Query() in view with model container attached shows error saying it does not have a model container

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have a function on a view that has a `modelContext` on its environment and that can successfully add data to the model container. But when in that same function I try to run a `Query()` function call I get this message on the console:

```
Set a .modelContext in view's environment to use Query
```

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?
The code is basically this:

```swift
let currentTrainPredicate = #Predicate<Train> { train in
    train.number == currentTrainNumber
}

// Update the value if it exists
if let currentTrain = Query(filter: currentTrainPredicate).wrappedValue.first {
    currentTrain.dateViewed = Date()
} else {
    self.train.dateViewed = Date()
    modelContext.insert(self.train)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are doing this in a function then use a [FetchDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/fetchdescriptor) instead of a Query since @Query is a property wrapper so you only use it when declaring a property.

```
let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Train>(predicate: currentTrainPredicate) 
let currentTrain = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor).first
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now, I don't entirely understand the difference between FetchDescriptor with .fetch() and a Query().

Comment: Query is a property wrapper so you only use it when declaring a property.